# tomcat can't establish ssl connection

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I can't establish ssl connnection with tomcat. Chrome writes `"107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"`. 
I've generated mystore file via keytool.(`>keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore mystore -validity 999 -keysize 512`) and put it to D:\mystore.

also in my server.xml:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="443"/>



<Connector port="443" SSLEnabled="true" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="200"
    enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"         
    acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="d:\mystore" keystorePass="123123" keystoreType="JKS"
    keyAlias="tomcat"/>
```

and when I starting tomcat in logs exist these strings :

```
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-443"]
сен 05, 2012 9:00:29 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
```

and when I try 
`https://localhost/lib` ( or `https://localhost:443/lib` ) nothing work.

Can somebody help me?

PS:
-apache-tomcat-7.0.29

-jdk1.7.0_5

**FIXED!**

migrate to apache-tomcat-7.0.28 ((((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED!

migrate to apache-tomcat-7.0.28 ((((

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should use the 8443 (or another 8000+ port), the 443 is one of the default ports that systems use (like FTP on 21 and so on).
Then: you should modify your server.xml like this:

```
<Connector port=”8443” protocol=”org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol” SSLEnabled=”true”
       maxThreads=”200” scheme=”https” secure=”true”  keystoreFile=”D:/mystore/.keystore” keystorePass=”123123”
       clientAuth=”false” sslProtocol=”TLS” />
```

in the keystoreFile option, you should verify that your file is named actually ".keystore" (withour brackets of course).
If you want to try and create another one: you should do like this:

```
keytool –genkey –alias tomcat –keyalg RSA
```

You should use the "backslash", "\", in the keystoreFile not the "/".
then on the restart of your application server, you should try to go to

```
https://localhost:8443/
```

let me know if helps

Comment: I still don't know why it was not work, but I changed tomcat to 7.0.28 from 7.0.29 and now it works

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same problem, but even after upgrading tomcat the problem remained. 
I resolved the problem by clearing cache and cookies.

Answer (score 1):

in your connector configuration include "sslEnabledProtocols" Here is a sample

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" keystoreFile="" keystorePass="password" />
```