# Windows Tomcat set ssl,when client : Error parsing HTTP request header

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have a question 
After I change the tomcat to https
the client https:/url:8443 will show "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

this is my server.xml setting

```
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="10485760" 
           enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
           acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true" 
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystoreFile="C:\keystores" keystorePass="pwd"
          />
```

and tomcat log like this

```
08-Apr-2016 18:25:02.364 INFO [http-nio-8443-exec-2] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing HTTP request header


Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -64
```

Comment: Have you refer this: [tomcat-cant-establish-ssl-connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275436/tomcat-cant-establish-ssl-connection)

Comment: I have read it before and my tomcat version is 8.0.30, I'm try to use pkcs12 but when I connect It still occur Error and msg is

Comment: [http-nio-443-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.